# Lebesgue theory and equivalence integral-series

Tags: calculus, lebesgue-integral

I have this exercise, but I really don't know how to start. Prove that:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^n\frac{1}{(2n)(2n)!}}=\int_0^1{\sin{x}\log{x}dx}$$. How can I approach this kind of exercises in general?

Comment: sin(x) = $\sum{\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}}$

Comment: For log I forgot

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use 
$$ \sin x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)!}x^{2n-1}, \int_0^1x^n\ln x=-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}.$$